# xml: japanese encoding

Tags: xml, unicode, encoding, character-encoding

I am making an xml document with japanese strings in it. I have tried different encodings but everytime when I save the file, it replaces the japanese strings with "??????".. I have a very brief sample code here.. Please advise me towards what encoding should I use for the xml doc.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<config>
        <start_text>転送</start_text>
</config>
```

Please advise me regarding what encoding should I use so that the japanese characters are retained even after saving and closing the xml doc. 
Thanks all

Comment: so... where is the sample code?

Comment: just have a look at the three or four lines of code I have mentioned in my code and please advise me regarding why the japanese characters are not saved and they are replaced by "??"..

Comment: You need to tell us *exactly* what you did and what you saw. Which programs did you use, how did you display the characters on the screen, which operating system, how many question marks were there, and so on. Tell us the complete story.

Comment: @Farhan that is your sample data, which means absolutely nothing to how it is being saved or what the problem might be. You need to show us a sample of your code if you want an answer.

Comment: thank you all of you for your vote down.. I don't want any answer now. I have found the solution.. @liho1eye, please ask your friends at stackoverflow to join this question and vote down.. If the question is not understandable, a comment would have been enough.. But please continue voting down the question and ask your friends to do so as well. Really greatful to you for your help..

Comment: Hover your mouse over the down button and read it. I think your question fits into that category. Contrary to what you may think, downvote is not a punishment or sign of hostility. It is exactly what the tooltip says.

Comment: Oh.. Sorry I didn't read that the tooltip also says that you must either select a downvote or a up vote.. I haven't asked you whether the question fits into that category or not.. Do whatever you like and stop commenting now.. I found the solution.. Many thanks for your downvote..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two Japanese characters in your XML file, and you get six question marks. This smells like UTF-8 encoding, as mentioned in your XML file. There are several possibilities:

The program that reads the XML file reads it with encoding ASCII, and therefore replaces every byte outside the ASCII range with a question mark.

The program reads the XML file properly, but then prints the UTF-8 encoded bytes to some output channel using the ASCII encoding, replacing each out-of-range byte with a question mark.

(Side note: If the output were `è»¢é??` it would be UTF-8 printed to an ISO-8859-1 output channel. But it seems to be six question marks.)

You need to find out at which places the following transformations happen:

- A byte sequence is transformed to a character sequence. (Probably in the XML reader.)
- A character sequence is transformed to a byte sequence.
- A byte (or character) sequence is transformed into a glyph sequence. (For displaying them; this may be an editor or a console.)

Comment: Sir.. sorry for the mistake. I got two question marks